# simple Data.Serialize "too few bytes"

Tags: haskell

Not sure how reason about this run-time error:

```
hdr or err: too few bytes
From:   demandInput
```

from the following:

```
module Main (main) where

import GHC.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Serialize
import Data.Serialize.Get
import Data.Serialize.Put

data Header =
  Header { ty      :: Word8
         , len     :: Word16
         } deriving (Show)

instance Serialize Header where
  put (Header ty len) = do
    putWord8 ty
    putWord16be len
  get = do
    ty  <- getWord8    >>= return . fromIntegral
    len <- getWord16be >>= return . fromIntegral
    return (Header ty len)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let bs = encode (Header 1 2)
  let str = case (runGet get bs) of
        Left err -> err
        Right fr -> fr
  putStrLn $ "hdr or err: " ++ str
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let str = case (runGet get bs) of
        Left err -> err
        Right fr -> fr
```

The inferred type of `fr` here is `String`, since that's the type of `err` and the alternatives of a case expression must have the same type. Therefore, it's using the `Serialize` instance for `String` to decode the result, which is obviously not what you intended.

To fix this, first add `show` to convert the decoded result to a string instead of forcing it to be a string itself. Then, add a type annotation to resolve the now-ambiguous type of `fr`.

```
let str = case (runGet get bs) of
        Left err -> err
        Right fr -> show (fr :: Header)
```